# Loop and condition not working

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, conditional-statements

The user enters an ID and if it exists it should display that it already exists and loop back to the inout section again. But for some reason its not doing that. At the end of it I have code that writes to a file that executes even tho I have a condition in there for it not to. I have tried several things and have no idea why it wont work.

```
JTextField aaField = new JTextField(5);
JTextField bbField = new JTextField(10);
JTextField ccField = new JTextField(10);   
JTextField ddField = new JTextField(10);
JTextField eeField = new JTextField(5);
JTextField ffField = new JTextField(5);
boolean done = false;
while(done == false) {
    JPanel myPanel1 = new JPanel();
    myPanel1.add(new JLabel("ID:"));
    myPanel1.add(aaField);
    myPanel1.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
    myPanel1.add(new JLabel("Name:"));
    myPanel1.add(bbField);
    myPanel1.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
    myPanel1.add(new JLabel("Address:"));
    myPanel1.add(ccField); // a spacer
    myPanel1.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
    myPanel1.add(new JLabel("Email:"));
    myPanel1.add(ddField);
    myPanel1.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    myPanel1.add(new JLabel("Password:"));
    myPanel1.add(eeField);  // a spacer
    myPanel1.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
    myPanel1.add(new JLabel("dob:"));
    myPanel1.add(ffField);  // a spacer
    result1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel1, 
                "Please Enter Values", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

    for(int xx = 0; xx< course.size();xx++) {  
        ch = course.get(xx).getId();    
        if(aaField.getText().matches(ch)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter an ID that doesnt already exist.");
        }
        if(!(aaField.getText().matches(ch))) {
            done = true;
        }
    }
}
if(done == true && !(aaField.getText().matches(ch))&& result1 ==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
    Mate a = new Mate();
    a.addMate(aaField.getText(),bbField.getText(),ccField.getText(),ddField.getText(),eeField.getText(),ffField.getText());
}
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: wow that's a big block of badly formatted code.  I noticed at the end you have if(done = true &&... which is assignment, you probably want comparison if(done == true && ...

Comment: Format Your Code Please...

Comment: EVEN when i change that it doesnt work

Comment: done just changed it there

Answer (score 1):

*"...I have a condition in there for it not to."* It looks like you do but you basically don't.

```
for(int xx = 0; xx< course.size();xx++) {  
    ch = course.get(xx).getId();    
    if(aaField.getText().matches(ch)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter an ID that doesnt already exist.");
    }
    if(!(aaField.getText().matches(ch))) {
        done = true;
    }
}
```

I assume `course` is some kind of list where you are fetching some kind of existing values from. If you examine this code you will realize that `done` will *always be true if any value in course does not match*.

I think what you want is basically this somewhat reversed structure:

```
boolean done = true;
do {

    // your giant block

    for (int i = 0; i < course.size(); i++) {
        if (aaField.getText().matches(course.get(i).getId())) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entry cannot be a duplicate.");
            done = false;
            break;
        }
    }

} while (!done);
```

As a side note your code is messy. This is OK if you are a beginner but you need to work on it. For starters, don't create GUI components inside of a loop.

Also you are using the method [matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) and I doubt you have a list of [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) so you probably want to be using the method [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) instead:

```
if (aaField.getText().equals(ch)) {
```

Unless you do indeed have a list of regex for whatever reason in which case regex away I guess.